# Django Rest framework - I am trying to convert a property received in Response object to JSON object and iterate through it. But response is string

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

In views.py VENDOR_MAPPER is list of dictionary each dictionary has id, name, placeholder and autocommit key. I also tried sending json instead of Response object.

```
resp_object = {}
resp_object['supported_vendors'] = VENDOR_MAPPER
resp_object['vendor_name'] = ""
resp_object['create_vo_entry'] = False
resp_object['generate_signature_flag'] = False
resp_object['branch_flag'] = False
resp_object['trunk_flag'] = False
resp_object['branch_name'] = ""
resp_object['advisory'] = ""
data = {'data': resp_object}
return Response(data)
```

On home.html I am accessing the vendors_supported which is list and iterate through it, however instead of object i am getting string as type of variable.

```
var supported_vendors = "{{data.supported_vendors|safe}}";
console.log(supported_vendors);
console.log("Supported_vendors ", supported_vendors);
console.log("Supported_vendors_type:", typeof(supported_vendors));
```

data.supported_vendors|safe (django template tagging) is used to remove the unwanted characters in the response i have also tried without safe, but still the type was string

also tried converted as well as parse the response but type is shown as string

```
var supported_vendors = "{{data.supported_vendors}}";
console.log(JSON.parse(supported_vendors));
console.log(JSON.stringify(supported_vendors));
```

Output generated, i have printed the response type and values i get, also converting using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify did not work and output every time was string
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuSMb.png

I want to convert the property into javascript object and perform some computations

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead ,

```
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), 
   content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I am using django templates, if jsonResponse is used I wont be able to render the output of templates.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thans, but i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
    var supported_vendors = "{{data.supported_vendors}}";
```

Converted the above line to

```
    var supported_vendors = {{data.supported_vendors}};
```

*removed quotes from the variable*